# Flutter/Firestore save unprecise location of the user

Tags: flutter, firebase, geolocation

I want to save the position of the user of my Flutter app in Firebase.
This doesn't need to be precise, because I only want to show all the other users that are e.g. about 40m away from the user. I thought about separating the world into 40x40m squares and then only saving in which square the user is, so I can just use the where() function to check who is also in this square.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/geoqueries?